# ASP.Net Custom Errors is not working

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

I placed thin on my web.config file

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/PageNotFound.html" />
</customErrors>
```

to redirect my custom 404 page not found on the file above. But its not working.

Do I need to add other configurations and code to make this work? Am I missing something? That's the only configuration I did.

Answer (score 1):

you must add custom error to system.web like this:

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="err.aspx">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="403.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />

</customErrors>
```

Comment: It did not redirect.

Comment: i set this mode remotey only you must set it in On

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  <system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto"   >
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPage.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/ErrorPage.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```